# Capybara not rendering .js.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

Hi: I've been stuck on this test using Capybara for some days now and can't work out a solution.
Have some DOM modification to be performed using AJAX, long story short:

1) My ajax event triggers the request successfully:

```
$.ajax({ url: 'nice_url', data: data, complete: function() {debugger} 
});
```

2) The controller receives the request just fine:

```
def update_dom
<other stuff>
  respond_to do |format|
     format.js
  end
end
```

3) IMPORTANT: the file update_dom.js.erb is correctly rendered in DEV environment but NOT in the test using Capybara + RSpec.

```
update_dom.js.erb:
debugger; //first line, breakopint no stopp in Test
<% unless %W(boolean datetime).include?(@operators[:type])%>
$.each($('.values'), function(i, valueField){
<other stuff, etc...>
```

This is actually the whole issue and will appreciate any thoughts on it

Comment: Are you actually using javascript driver to run this particular Capybara test? Without this no javascript will be triggered. Basic, but just to be sure!

Comment: Hi, @TomD: thanks for your comment. I assume you're referring to have the option `js: true`, which is there in my test, yes.

Comment: could you edit your post to include your rails_helper.rb and your spec code?
Also, just thinking about it, debugger js declaration stops js with debug tools enabled, not quite sure those are there in automated tests. Could you try and in js.erb change debugger to something like <% raise "Error" %> and see if it actually errors out in dev AND test?

Comment: TomD is probably correct here, with the selenium driver `debugger` in your JS won't do anything unless you've already opened the developer console in the browser (pause the test after visiting the page, open the dev console, then continue the test)

Answer (score 0):

I had an error on my `*.js.erb` file which was not being reflected on the developers' console stack trace. I was able to debug it using following guide (used plain firefox instead of firebug but still worked): [solution](https://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-js-erb-remote-response-not-executing/)